# Moore–Penrose inverse of the square root

Tags: operator-theory

I'm seeking the Moore–Penrose inverse of the square root (if it exists) for a generalized invertible operator T. I've looked into whether it's the square root of its Moore–Penrose inverse but haven't found a reference.
Can anyone point me to relevant literature on this topic?

Comment: the square root is not uniquely defined, is it?

Comment: What happens in simple (non-invertible) cases?  Like $2 \times 2$ matries?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker As far as I know it is unique. To see this you can visit this page for example

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595714/show-that-the-square-root-of-a-non-negative-operator-is-unique

Answer (score 4):

**Q:** Is the square root of the Moore-Penrose inverse equal to the Moore-Penrose inverse of the square root?

**A:** No, here is a simple counter example, for the positive semi-definite matrix $M={{1\,0}\choose{1\,0}}$:
$$M^{1/2}={{1\,0}\choose{1\,0}},\;\;(M^{1/2})^+=\frac{1}{2}{{1\,1}\choose{0\,0}},$$
but
$$M^+=\frac{1}{2}{{1\,1}\choose{0\,0}},\;\;(M^+)^{1/2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}{{1\,1}\choose{0\,0}},$$
so the two answers differ by a factor $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: I get it now thanks